# packer image failed during script

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, packer

I'm trying to build a windows based AMI on AWS with packer and providing the image with powershell script.
For some reason, the build is terminated in the middle of the script and I can't figure the cause since the script is evaluated to run manually.

Here's the part of my PS script where the build ends:

```
function DownloadFile([Object[]] $sourceFiles, [string]$targetDirectory) {
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

foreach ($sourceFile in $sourceFiles) {
    $sourceFileName = $sourceFile.SubString($sourceFile.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    $targetFileName = $targetDirectory + $sourceFileName
    $wc.DownloadFile($sourceFile, $targetFileName)
    Write-Host "Downloaded $sourceFile to file location $targetFileName"
}}
```

The files are downloaded and then the build stops with the following error:

> amazon-ebs: Downloaded File01 to file location D:\file1.exe
>       amazon-ebs: Downloaded file1 to file location D:\File2.exe
>       amazon-ebs: Downloaded file3 to file location D:\File3.exe
>   ==> amazon-ebs: Stopping the source instance...
>       amazon-ebs: Stopping instance, attempt 1
>   ==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for the instance to stop...
>   ==> amazon-ebs: Deregistered AMI PACKER-DEMO-tls, id: ami-3e5a3e51

What can be the cause for the build to stop?

Comment: There is a regression with the WinRM communicator in 1.1.3. It can be worth downgrading to 1.1.2 and se if it works with that.

Comment: Is there an open issue that I can see and track?

Comment: @TomerLeibovich did you get this working? Packer 1.2.0 came out a few days after your post and might have resolved this. If not, you might try `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of using WebClient - I've had no problems using it with 1.2.0. I know WebClient is supposed to be faster for larger files, but it might be worth trying if you haven't already.